Scientific literature on de-indexing algorithms
I would like to know more about the topic of de-indexing algorithms, i.e., removing results from the search engines' index. I am interested in the theoretical basics, before moving on to more complex (and maybe real-life) scenarios. However, while there is a huge literature about indexing, searching for "de-indexing algorithms" mostly yields discussions and surveys about law frameworks, the right to be forgotten, etc.
Do you have any suggestion and/or pointers to technical discussions/papers about de-indexing algorithms from an information retrieval perspective? At this stage of my research, also divulgative or high-level content could be fine.
